# data Remediation query

Tags: mysql, sql

Let us assume a table like below. The query needed to build includes:

- where there are more than with same *id*, *value* and same *type*, the records must be deleted to where only one record remains.
- keep the record with the earliest *effectiveDate* and update the record with latest *expirationDate* and remaining to be deleted.

**input table**

```
p.key | id   | value   | type  | effectiveDate  |  expirationDate
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1    | 123  | ABC     | 1D    | 2000-01-01     | 2010-01-01
 2    | 123  | ABC     | 1D    | 1990-01-01     | 2010-01-01
 3    | 123  | ABC     | 1D    | 2010-01-01     | 2020-01-01
 4    | 456  | ABC     | 1D    | 2000-01-01     | 2010-01-01
```

**expected output**

```
p.key | id   | value   | type  | effectiveDate  |  expirationDate
------------------------------------------------------------------
 2    | 123  | ABC     | 1D    | 1990-01-01     | 2020-01-01
 4    | 456  | ABC     | 1D    | 2000-01-01     | 2010-01-01
```

Comment: This is a very simple aggregate query. Please read up on the `GROUP BY` query and make an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple aggregation. You'll need to use a `group by` clause and the `min()` and `max()` functions.

```
select
  id
  , value
  , type
  , min(effectiveDate) as effectiveDate
  , max(expirationDate) as expirationDate
from
  my_table
group by
  id
  , value
  , type
```

Note: I've removed the `key` column from your output since it doesn't make sense to have it in here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply .. and I want to delete the remaining records

Comment: @prabeenKumar There are no *remaining* records to delete. The result returned from this query doesn't match anything in your existing table. If it were me, I would set this query up as a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html), or maintain the results in a new table that gets ETL'd on a regular basis.

Comment: this query is giving me what I am expecting. but i want to clean up my table like below >> where there are more than with same id, value and same type, the records must be deleted to where only one record remains.
keep the record with the earliest effectiveDate and update the record with latest expirationDate and remaining to be deleted.

Comment: @prabeenKumar: Then use this query to insert the records returned into a new table and delete from this one. What you want doesn't make sense from a database design/maintainability practice. You should look into [staging tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data))

Comment: @prabeenKumar: that being said, unless you have an incredible amount of data, there's really no reason to not simply query the data in this manner every time you need the results. Why throw away all your history?